# Convert string elements to class attributes (py 2.7)

Tags: python, oop, class

i have a string, and i want to use the elements to convert them into attrs of a class.

```
@staticmethod
def impWords():
    #re

    tempFile = open('import.txt','r+')
    tempFile1 = re.findall(r'\w+', tempFile.read())

    for i in range(len(tempFile1)):
        new=word(word.id=i,word.data=str(tempFile1[i]), word.points=int(tempFile1[i]+1))
        Repo.words.append(word)
    print str(Repo.words)
```

the following error pops up, how can i repair this i tried some ideas i had but it didnt worked out.

```
File "D:\info\F P\Lab\lab5.7\Scramble\Repository\Rep.py", line 82, in impWords
new=word(id=int(i),data=str(tempFile1[i]), points=int(tempFile1[i]+1))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: `(tempFile1[i]+1))` cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects. What are you trying to do.?

Comment: word(word.id=i,word.data=str(tempFile1[i]), word.points=int(tempFile1[i]+1)) what is that strange construction

Comment: Process:
1 import file
2 splitt it
3 from de new lsit create objects of 'word' class
(tempFile1[i]+1)) < to refer to the i+1 positon elemnt because the lsit will have 1 word 1 str 1 word one str construction... after splitting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int(tempFile1[i]+1)
```

Your `tmpFile[i]` is a string. You cannot add the integer `1` to a string. You can try to convert your string into an integer and add the one afterwards:

```
int(tempFile1[i])+1
```

So the whole line looks like this:

```
new=word(word.id=i,word.data=str(tempFile1[i]), word.points=int(tempFile1[i])+1)
```

**UPDATE:** Anyway, this is probably not going to work. Consider this alternative (you have to define the word-class properly):

```
@staticmethod
def impWords():
    with open('import.txt','r+') as f:
        for i, word in enumerate(re.findall(r'\w+', f.read())):
            Repo.words.append(word(id=i, data=word, points = int(word)+1))
```

Comment: class word():
    def __init__(self,ID,data,points):
        self.ID = ID
        self.data = data
        self.points=points
        
        ID = int 
        data = str
        points = int   
        
    def prt(self):
        print 'ID: ' + str(self.ID) + '   word: ' +str(self.data)+'   pts value: '+str(self.points)

Is it wrong? or whyat shouldi  repair exaclly

Comment: @BogdanMaier - cannot read your definition within the comment (newlines missing), but probably it is ok how you define it. Just pay attention to the case (ID/id).

Answer (score 1):

If you whant to solve your problem? Just make int(tempFile1[i]) + 1, but this code is absolutely not python way.

```
f = file('your_file')
ids_words = enumerate(re.findall(r'\w', f.read()))
out_mas = [word(word.id = id, word.data = data, word.points = int(data) + 1) for id, data in ids_words]
```

Comment: thank you i`m  beginner in programming and i work on a scramble game atm,  i hope with  tiem i`ll improve the gaps i have. I study programming for like 4 months :)

Comment: As i understand your comment at start of the topic you use (tempFile1[i]+1)) to go to the next possition? If this is right, you are not right. I post my explain in answer below

Answer (score 0):

So if understand this is what you want

```
class Word(object):
    def __init__(self, id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data

f = file('your_file')
result = [Word(id, data) for id, data in enumerate(re.findall(r'\w+', f.read()))]
```

But if you want get a count of each word in file look at mapreduce algorithm