# Create from list of strings list of class instances py2.7

Tags: python, oop, list, class, instance

My code creats only the last instance times len(list) how can i change this to create every instance separatly? :|

```
 @staticmethod
def impWords():
    tempFile = open('import.txt','r+')
    tempFile1 = re.findall(r'\w+', tempFile.read())
    tempFile.close()

    for i in range(0,len(tempFile1)):

        word.ID = i 
        word.data = tempFile1[i]
        word.points = 0
        Repo.words.append(word)
        word.prt(word)
    print str(Repo.words)
    UI.Controller.adminMenu()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `word` is an instance of `Word`, you should create a new one in each iteration, like this:

```
@staticmethod
def impWords():

    with open('import.txt','r+') as tempFile:
        #re
        tempFile1 = re.findall(r'\w+', tempFile.read())
        # using enumerate here is cleaner
        for i, w in enumerate(tempFile1): 
            word = Word() # here you're creating a new Word instance for each item in tempFile1
            word.ID = i 
            word.data = w
            word.points = 0
            Repo.words.append(word)
            word.prt(word) # here it would be better to implement Word.__str__() and do print word

    print Repo.words # print automatically calls __str__()
    UI.Controller.adminMenu()
```

Now if your `Word` class `__init__` takes `ID`, `data` and `points` as parameters, and `Repo.words` is a list you can reduce that to:

```
@staticmethod
def impWords():

    with open('import.txt','r+') as tempFile:
        #re
        tempFile1 = re.findall(r'\w+', tempFile.read())
        # using enumerate here is cleaner
        Repo.words.extend(Word(i, w, 0) for i, w in enumerate(tempFile1))

    print Repo.words # print automatically calls __str__()
    UI.Controller.adminMenu()
```

Comment: From a previous comment [his class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141883/convert-string-elements-to-class-attributes-py-2-7#comment11492731_9141905) takes id, data, and points in its `__init__`.

Comment: @DSM didn't notice it's a double